# How to implement full cart system in Ionic 3?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, cart

Hello I have just created a cart system following the https://www.joshmorony.com/add-to-cart-with-the-web-animations-api-in-ionic/ tutorial. I might be doing some silly mistake or my logic might be wrong. When I add same product multiple times /another element is created in object rather then modifying just the quantity of that particular element. please help.. Here is my Home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ListPage } from '../list/list';

@Component({
selector: 'page-home',
templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

items : Object[] = [];
itemsInCart: Object[] = [];

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

this.items = [
{ 'name': 'Hello World', quantityInCart: 0 , id: 1},
{ 'name': 'Hello1 World', quantityInCart: 0 , id: 2},
{ 'name': 'Hello2 World', quantityInCart: 0 , id: 3},
{ 'name': 'Hello3 World', quantityInCart: 0 , id: 4}
];
}

addToCart(item) {
item.quantityInCart += 1;
this.itemsInCart.push(item); 
console.log(this.itemsInCart);

localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(this.itemsInCart));
}

goToList() {
this.navCtrl.push(ListPage);
}

}
```

[image]

[image]

I want the output to be

```
[{…}]0: {name: "Hello World", quantityInCart: 2, id: 1}
```

Thanks

Comment: What are you passing to `addToCart ` method?

Comment: And most probably the error will be in the view

Comment: I am passing item ie { 'name': 'Hello World', quantityInCart: 0 , id: 1}

Comment: their is no error, I just want to have one row if the same item is selected  multiple times not another row for each select

Comment: you are pushing to the cart on each individual select. That may lead to multiple select of items in cart of the same genre

Comment: @kevin https://github.com/Aadencoder/ionic-basic-cart-system here is github code..